# Getting a NotADirectoryError when running selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, beautifulsoup

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

my_username = "username"
my_password = "pass"

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("http://www.twitch.tv/user/login")
elem_user = driver.find_element_by_id("login_user_login")
elem_passwd = driver.find_element_by_id("user[password]")
elem_user.send_keys(my_username)
elem_passwd.send_keys(my_password + Keys.RETURN)
time.sleep(5)

html = driver.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
logginTag = soup.find("a", {"id" : "user_display_name"})
print(logginTag)
driver.close()
```

> error- driver = webdriver.Firefox()   File
> "/Users/grey/.pyenv/versions/3.7.3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/webdriver.py",
> line 164, in **init**
> self.service.start()   File "/Users/grey/.pyenv/versions/3.7.3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 76, in start
> stdin=PIPE)   File "/Users/grey/.pyenv/versions/3.7.3/lib/python3.7/subprocess.py", line
> 775, in **init**
> restore_signals, start_new_session)   File "/Users/grey/.pyenv/versions/3.7.3/lib/python3.7/subprocess.py", line
> 1522, in _execute_child
> raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg, err_filename) NotADirectoryError: [Errno 20] Not a directory: 'geckodriver'

Answer (score 0):

Baseed on

```
NotADirectoryError: [Errno 20] Not a directory: 'geckodriver'
```

suggest:

- Make sure you have successfully installed Fixefox, to verify it by starting firefox in the console
- Download geckodriver binary from https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases, note that geckodriver must match with Firefox version
- Set the path. demo  `driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=r'/User/xxx/geckodriver')`

Comment: that doesnt work for me i get this error now https://throwbin.io/FRmNFqo

Comment: @Juzec Based on `selenium.common.exceptions.SessionNotCreatedException: Message: Unable to find a matching set of capabilities` you gave, I want to ask a question, is firefox installed on your computer?

Answer (score 0):

When you are working with browser you need driver instance to interect , for example if you want to work chrome driver you need chrome driver exe and if you want open firefox you need gecko driver

https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases you can download latest driver from this link and setup path also and rerun project

Comment: thanks for the answer but i already have the geckodrive executable downloaded and i also used - driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path='/Users/grey/Downloads/geckodriver')

Comment: now i get this error

  https://throwbin.io/FRmNFqo

Comment: did you do changes in firefox setting ?

Comment: like? also i am using a mac if that changes anything

Comment: and i dont have the firefox browser installed

Comment: please install firefox first latest version i am also using macbook , without firefox how can you run test ?

Comment: i am super dumb sorry